# react-draggable for individual elements

Tags: reactjs

thanks for your help.

I'm trying to make span tags which contain a single word draggable, by using react-draggable. The text lines come from a json file. How can I apply the functionality to each word rather than the whole line? I'm using @moxy/react-split-text to split the text into separate words to apply a span tag and this is currently working. Maybe I could do it another way? Thanks in advance, much appreciated.

```
          {this.state.poem.map((item, i) => (
            <div key={"block-" + i}>
              {item.lines.map((line, i) => (
                <div key={"line-" + i}>
                  <Draggable handle=".word">
                    <SplitText className="word">{line}</SplitText>
                  </Draggable>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>{line.split(' ').map(word => <span className="word">{word}</span>)}</div>
```

You could split it yourself into different words, of course the above only will split between a single white space, it all depends on how your text looks like, to handle all situations

Comment: Thank you! That worked when I used another package called Drag and Drop Container